# 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4675 pos 16: 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make a simple homepage and whenever I Run the program, I get this error and it keeps shows the same error

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown building DefaultTextStyle(debugLabel: (englishLike bodyMedium 2014).merge(blackMountainView bodyMedium), inherit: false, color: Color(0xdd000000), family: Roboto, size: 14.0, weight: 400, baseline: alphabetic, decoration: TextDecoration.none, softWrap: wrapping at box width, overflow: clip):
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4675 pos 16: 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.


Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.md

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Scaffold Scaffold:file:///C:/Users/taehy/AndroidStudioProjects/surrfy/lib/pages/homepage.dart:30:12
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      Element.rebuild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4675:16)
#3      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4678:8)
#4      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4934:5)
#5      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5108:11)
#6      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4928:5)
...     Normal element mounting (115 frames)
#121    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#122    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#123    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#260    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#261    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#262    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#399    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#400    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#401    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#538    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#539    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#540    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#677    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#678    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#679    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#816    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#817    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#818    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#955    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#956    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#957    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#1094   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#1095   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#1096   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#1233   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#1234   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#1235   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#1372   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#1373   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#1374   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#1511   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#1512   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#1513   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#1650   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#1651   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#1652   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#1789   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#1790   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#1791   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#1928   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#1929   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#1930   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#2067   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#2068   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#2069   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#2206   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#2207   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#2208   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#2345   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#2346   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#2347   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#2484   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#2485   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#2486   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#2623   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#2624   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#2625   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#2762   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#2763   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#2764   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#2901   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#2902   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#2903   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#3040   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#3041   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#3042   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#3179   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#3180   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#3181   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#3318   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#3319   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#3320   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#3457   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#3458   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#3459   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#3596   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#3597   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#3598   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#3735   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#3736   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#3737   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#3874   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#3875   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#3876   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#4013   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#4014   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#4015   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#4152   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#4153   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#4154   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#4291   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#4292   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#4293   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#4430   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#4431   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#4432   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#4569   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#4570   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#4571   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#4708   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#4709   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#4710   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#4847   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#4848   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#4849   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#4986   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#4987   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#4988   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#5125   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#5126   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#5127   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#5264   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#5265   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#5266   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#5403   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#5404   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#5405   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#5542   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#5543   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#5544   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#5681   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#5682   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#5683   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#5820   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#5821   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#5822   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#5959   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#5960   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#5961   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#6098   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#6099   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#6100   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#6237   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#6238   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#6239   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#6376   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#6377   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#6378   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#6515   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#6516   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#6517   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#6654   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#6655   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#6656   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#6793   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#6794   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#6795   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#6932   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#6933   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#6934   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#7071   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#7072   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#7073   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#7210   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#7211   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#7212   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#7349   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#7350   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#7351   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#7488   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#7489   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#7490   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#7627   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#7628   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#7629   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#7766   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#7767   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#7768   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#7905   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#7906   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#7907   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (137 frames)
#8044   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#8045   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#8046   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (326 frames)
#8372   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#8373   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6491:36)
#8374   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6503:32)
...     Normal element mounting (464 frames)
#8838   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3940:16)
#8839   Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3677:18)
#8840   RenderObjectToWidgetElement._rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1196:16)
#8841   RenderObjectToWidgetElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1165:5)
#8842   RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1112:18)
#8843   BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2689:19)
#8844   RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1111:13)
#8845   WidgetsBinding.attachRootWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:945:7)
#8846   WidgetsBinding.scheduleAttachRootWidget.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:925:7)
#8850   _RawReceivePort._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:192:26)
(elided 5 frames from class _AssertionError, class _Timer, and dart:async-patch)
====================================================================================================
```

I found out that this part:
     `body: _items[_selectedIndex],`
in my code was making this happen.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:surrfy/navbar_pages/favorites.dart';
import 'package:surrfy/navbar_pages/profile.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  void _navigatorBottomNavBar(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  final List<Widget> _items = [
    HomePage(),
    Favorites(),
    Profiles(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _items[_selectedIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        onTap: _navigatorBottomNavBar,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home, size: 35,), label: '',),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_outline, size: 35,), label: '',),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.person_outline_rounded, size: 35,), label: '',),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the whole code.

I want to make a navigation bottome navbar and make the pages change when I press on the icons, but this error keeps coming up.

Comment: please read this docs first for creating more understandable question => https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Your code generates an infinite loop of creating nested Home Page widgets here:
**body: _items[_selectedIndex]**
You could update the _items variable to stop this error:

```dart
final List<Widget> _items = [
    Text('Home Page'),
    Favorites(),
    Profiles(),
  ];
```

Hope this helps.